# Asp.net core: Call controller method onchange of drop-down list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a ViewComponent which is used in my layout. The ViewComponent contains a drop-down with a list of campaigns for a logged user. A selected item is a current campaign for a user (it stores in the database)

I want to handle onchange event of the drop-down list in such a way that:

1. Current Campaign for the user should be updated in the database.
2. The user should be redirected to the campaign summary page ("/CampaignSummary")

I suppose I should call a controller method in this case which will handle everything I need, but I don't understand how to do it directly from javascript.

I tried the following approach which didn't work for me:
handle onchange event in javascript and execute the following code there:

```
var selectedId = $("#CurrentCampaignDropdown").val();
$.get("/CampaignSummary", {currentCampaignId: selectedId});
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand? Have you made an attempt? What's preventing your attempt from working?

Comment: I tried to use jquery get call:
var selectedId = $("#CurrentCampaignDropdown").val();
$.get("/CampaignSummary", {currentCampaignId: selectedId});

But it doesn't work

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Does it not make the call at all. Do you get a 404, 400, 500, etc.? Is it just not doing anything (you have no success callback, so it won't actually *do* anything).

Comment: 1) Don't update via GET. Use POST. 2) You'd have to register a success callback for your AJAX, and then change the `location` there to redirect. However, doing that completely negates the point of AJAX. Just do a standard form post.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. My controller is ended with the following line: **return View("CampaignSummary")**. And the line is executed, but the web-page is not changed. It is still the same, and a user is not redirected to CampaignSummary page.

Comment: yes because you are using AJAX to post. Use `$("#formId").submit()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find out the solution to my problem.

In the end, I even don't need a javascript code at all except one line. Here is an example of my code:

**_Layout.cshtml** code:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync($"{ViewComponentName}", /* parameters for view component */)
```

**ViewComponent .cshtml** code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConrollerMethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("CurrentCampaignId", new SelectList(/* parameters */), new {onchange = "this.form.submit()"})
}
```

**Controller** code:

```
public IActionResult ControllerMethodName(int currentCampaignId) //The name of the parameter should be the same as the first parameter in DropDownList method. Otherwise, it will be null.
{
    //Save your data

    RedirectToAction(nameof(ActionYouNeed));
}
```

I hope it will help somebody.

Thanks to Chris Pratt and Avin Kavish for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Almost exactly three years later, this answer was exactly what I needed to save me from having to go figure it out myself. Thanks for following up!